# Как подключить файлы для админки в Materialize CSS?

Tags: css, вёрстка, material-design, materialize-css

Изучаю `materialize css`. Пытаюсь сделать с помощью него в админку такой же `header` как [тут](https://pixinvent.com/materialize-material-design-admin-template/html/horizontal-menu/). [отсюда](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) скачиваю материалы и беру стартовый HTML. Вставляю:

```
<div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">This is a card panel with a teal lighten-2 class</div>
```

CSS работает нормально. Но когда беру [отсюда](http://file:///Users/jussia/Downloads/materialize-admin-4.0/documentation/getting-started.html) стартовый HTML, то тот же

```
<div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">This is a card panel with a teal lighten-2 class</div>
```

уже не видит CSS.

Понимаю, что нет всех тех CSS и JS файлов, которые подключаются ко второму HTML. Откуда их можно скачать?